# My first WordPress theme from scratch. Enqueue stylesheets in the functions.php file

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress-theming

I am building my first WordPress theme from scratch, and I have managed to enqueue my fantasia.css stylesheet in functions.php. BUT I am also trying to add the normalize.css using the WordPress enqueue method. What order are the stylesheets loaded?.

```
<?php
function fantasia_style_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('fantasia', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/assets/stylesheets/css/fantasia.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

    wp_enqueue_style('fantasia', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/assets/stylesheets/normalize/normalize.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fantasia_style_enqueue');
?>
```

Comment: In order that you placed. In your code first will be `fantasia.css` second the `normalize.css`

Answer (score 0):

The order is the order you add it. In your case, first the fantasia and then the normalize. You probably want to do it in reverse.

Also, remember that you need to give a different "string handle" for your css. Both have "fantasia", so only one will be loaded.